# box-shadow artifacts due jQuery animate in the WebKit

Tags: html, webkit, css

When I try to apply jQuery animate method to the float block near the one with box-shadow, some artifacts take a place in the WebKit (i'm testing in the Chrome 18 & 19).

[image: box-shadow artifact]

Test case:
http://jsfiddle.net/JxBKM/

Are anybody knows how to prevent this?

Comment: not sure what artifacts take place... can you be more specific as to the issue?

Comment: Basically it's the skipping of the shadow. It's like it's not fully refreshing the animation. I get the problem. The problem is not as noticeable when the animation is sped up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JxBKM/1/) to include the animate:complete function. Basically it's a function called when the animation is completed. The fiddle I put together only works on the first time it's called though, because it's setting the background to something different than it initially was. For whatever reason Chrome doesn't want to do the animation then set the CSS again. Take a look and you'll see what I mean. It works the first time, but not subsequent attempts.

I recommend going with an image for box-shadow, or refining the fiddle to reset it every time rather than on the first time.